# Excel VBA worksheet sum function returns error when one of values is text

Tags: vba, excel, sum, runtime-error

I get this error:
"Run-time error '1004'""
Unable to get the Sum property of the Worksheetfunction class

I have a code that looks into multiple comboboxes in a userform and sums their values that the user selects. The code was working fine with only numbers in the combobox list. I recently added one text option into the list and I called it "Not applicable". However, once I run the code I get the above error.

I believe the error is because I introduced the text option, and the sum function in VBA wouldn't recognize it.

Is there anyway to solve this issue?

Thanks

Here is the code I used:

```
Dim totalscore As Double
totalscore = WorksheetFunction.Sum(frmQA.ComboBox3.Value, frmQA.ComboBox4.Value, frmQA.ComboBox5.Value, frmQA.ComboBox6.Value, frmQA.ComboBox7.Value, frmQA.ComboBox8.Value, frmQA.ComboBox9.Value)
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the text option is available in ComboBox3 adjust this part of the sum formula:

```
frmQA.ComboBox3.Value
```

To this:

```
Iif(IsNumeric(frmQA.ComboBox3.Value),frmQA.ComboBox3.Value,0)
```

If they all have the text option you can do this:

```
totalscore = totalscore + Iif(IsNumeric(frmQA.ComboBox3.Value),frmQA.ComboBox3.Value,0)
totalscore = totalscore + Iif(IsNumeric(frmQA.ComboBox4.Value),frmQA.ComboBox4.Value,0)
...
```

Comment: Hi Scott thanks your iif(Isnumeric) command was very helpful here is the code that I used

Comment: Dim totalscore As Double
      totalscore = WorksheetFunction.Sum(IIf(IsNumeric(frmQA.ComboBox3.Value), frmQA.ComboBox3.Value, 0), IIf(IsNumeric(frmQA.ComboBox4.Value), frmQA.ComboBox4.Value, 0), IIf(IsNumeric(frmQA.ComboBox5.Value), frmQA.ComboBox5.Value, 0), IIf(IsNumeric(frmQA.ComboBox6.Value), frmQA.ComboBox6.Value, 0), IIf(IsNumeric(frmQA.ComboBox7.Value), frmQA.ComboBox7.Value, 0), IIf(IsNumeric(frmQA.ComboBox8.Value), frmQA.ComboBox8.Value, 0), IIf(IsNumeric(frmQA.ComboBox9.Value), frmQA.ComboBox9.Value, 0))

Comment: glad it worked. please mark as answered so others know going forward.

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: there's a grey check mark right below the downvote arrow (also grey). click that @exlover

Answer (score 0):

It may be better to verify whether the entry made, by the user, is a text or numeric value before processing is done.

From a cursory glance at the code - I can surmise that the "text value" may go along the lines of '123 (see apostrophe mark).It's possible, but that would be a conscientious effort by the end user.

So,therefore IMHO, it would be better to run a validation check before the calculation (as suggested by Scott Holtzman).

"Not Applicable" - either use the number zero (0) in the code or somehow get your VBA to map "Not Applicable" and change this entry to zero(0) value.

Pseudo code example:

```
IF frmQA.ComboBox3.Value = "NOT Applicable" then

        frmQA.ComboBox3.Value = 0
END IF
```

The above suggestion can be placed in a worksheet event, perhaps

Best of luck

Regards

RDFS

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer modified as suggested by Scott

```
Dim totalscore As Double
totalscore = WorksheetFunction.Sum(IIf(IsNumeric(frmQA.ComboBox3.Value), frmQA.ComboBox3.Value, 0), IIf(IsNumeric(frmQA.ComboBox4.Value), frmQA.ComboBox4.Value, 0), IIf(IsNumeric(frmQA.ComboBox5.Value), frmQA.ComboBox5.Value, 0), IIf(IsNumeric(frmQA.ComboBox6.Value), frmQA.ComboBox6.Value, 0), IIf(IsNumeric(frmQA.ComboBox7.Value), frmQA.ComboBox7.Value, 0), IIf(IsNumeric(frmQA.ComboBox8.Value), frmQA.ComboBox8.Value, 0), IIf(IsNumeric(frmQA.ComboBox9.Value), frmQA.ComboBox9.Value, 0))
```